# Batch script if else command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to make a simple batch script to wipe/zero a flash drive and reformat it. It's for others, so i'm attempting to make it relatively safe, by blocking formatting to C:, D:, etc.

I'm looking for an IF ELSE type command i can use, to be an error catch-all.

Here's (the main portion of) what i have ATM

```
:again
echo.
cls
echo.
echo  Please select the drive letter for the flash
echo  drive you wish to erase
echo.
echo    **** DO NOT SELECT C: OR D: ****
echo.
echo.
echo   *** Enter letter (no colon) ONLY e.g. "E" ***
echo.
set /p answer=
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "e" format E: /x /fs:FAT32 /v:FORENSICS /p:2
if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "f" format F: /x /fs:FAT32 /v:FORENSICS /p:2
if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "g" format G: /x /fs:FAT32 /v:FORENSICS /p:2
if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "h" format H: /x /fs:FAT32 /v:FORENSICS /p:2
if /i "%answer:~,1%" NOT exist goto again && echo    Please provide a valid drive letter for flash drive
echo.
```

Now I know that

```
if /i "%answer:~,1%" NOT exist goto again && echo    Please provide a valid drive letter for flash drive
```

is not valid syntax, but what could I use in order to achieve the same goal? I know there is a more effecient way to do this (e.g. instead of defining 4 variables for likely drive letters, put a single variable that listens to user input and accepts it if it exists.)

This is my first foray into batch scripting (and scripting in general) and i'm learning on-the-fly, so  the "dumber" you can make it, the better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You also need to escape the parenthesis in your echo command.

Comment: where does this parenthesis need to be placed? I placed it after "flash drive" and the command looped.

Comment: In your code where it has something like echo blah... (no colon) ... you need to escape the brackets. I'm on my phone so you can see my problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo.%answer:~,1% | findstr /r /i "[e-h]"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  format %answer:~,1%: /x /fs:FAT32 /v:FORENSICS /p:2
) else (
  echo Please provide a valid drive letter for flash drive.
  goto again
)
```